# AutoFixture AutoData with arguments

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

How can you specify arguments for `AutoData`?

For example I have the following in my code:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(
   new TypeRelay(
      typeof (IOrder),
      typeof (Order)));
```

I would like to have a test run several times with different fixture data. How would I set stuff like:

`.Customizations.Add()` or `.Build()`/`.With`/`.Do` so that when using `AutoData` fixture has this specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [package various repeated AutoFixture customizations into one or more Customizations](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations).

For the particular example, it'd look like this:

```
public class OrderCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new TypeRelay(
                typeof(IOrder),
                typeof(Order)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new OrderCustomization());
var order = fixture.Create<IOrder>();
```

You can use them with `[AutoData]` by [creating a derived attribute that passes a Fixture instance to the appropriate base class constructor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture).